# React route params with default value

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react functional component with react router v5 . I am using useParam function to fetch a param. How can I set default value of the param when it is not available or undefined.

My router code

```
<Switch>
    // ....
    // .... 
    <Route path="/users/:userId?" component={UserInfo} />
    // ....
</Switch>
```

My component code

```
export const UserInfo = (props) => {
    const {userId} = useParams()


    // ... other codes 
}
```

I am getting `undefined` when calling http://localhost:3000/users/.

Any idea will be helpful.

Comment: Do you have another route in your `Switch` that ***should*** match "/users"?

Comment: I have another route with exact `<Route path="/users" exact={true} component={Users} />`

Comment: Can you update your question to include your full `Router` and routes then? I suspect you may just need to adjust the order of some routes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you don't have another route in your `Switch` that matches "/users", you can just provide a fallback value for the destructured params object for the "/users/:userId" path.

```
export const UserInfo = (props) => {
    const { userId = /* fallback value */ } = useParams();

    // ... other codes 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I used it this way:

```
export const UserInfo = (props) => {
   // assuming 1 is the default value
   const {userId = 1} = useParams()
  // ... other codes 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `useParams()` function in your router you can use `props.match` and check the condition.

Instead

```
const {userId} = useParams()
```

Use

```
// assuming 0 is the default value
const userId = props.match?.userId || 0;
```